# Find unique records in F# List of List

Tags: list, f#, record

I have a record called Move that is defined as follows:

```
type Move = {
X : int
Y : int
By: CellState }
```

I have created a list of list of moves (`Move list list`) to store some data. I want to remove duplicate entries from this list. Each sublist in my example has the same contents but in a different order. It looks as follows when printed:

```
[[{X = 5;
   Y = 1;
   By = R;}; {X = 5;
              Y = 0;
              By = B;}; {X = 4;
                         Y = 0;
                         By = B;}]; [{X = 5;
                                      Y = 0;
                                      By = B;}; {X = 4;
                                                 Y = 0;
                                                 By = B;}; {X = 5;
                                                            Y = 1;
                                                            By = R;}];
 [{X = 4;
   Y = 0;
   By = B;}; {X = 5;
              Y = 1;
              By = R;}; {X = 5;
                         Y = 0;
                         By = B;}]]
```

This list contains 3 lists that each have 3 records. Each list has the same records but in a different order. I want to know if there's a way to remove the duplicate sublists from the main list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order the sublists then `List.distinct` will do the trick:

```
yourList 
|> List.map List.sort
|> List.distinct
```

Comment: How can I order the sublists?

Comment: I did it in the above snippet with List.map and List.sort